# how to boot or suspend vagrant when all files in .vagrant is lost?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, vagrant-windows

first_vagcode is a vm created in folder f:\vagvms\vagcode, it can still be booted from vbox gui, but i can never boot it using `vagrant up` now, it seems `vagrant status` cannot even discovery right now, i hacked, and find all metadata inside .vagrant is lost, i know know what happened, **my question is how to boot this vm using `vagrant up`, should i regenerate files in .vagrant for this vm? or i should add something to Vagrantfile? but how to do this?**

btw, i am using win7 x64

```
    F:\vagvms\vagcode>vagrant status
    Current machine states:

    default                   not created (virtualbox)

    The environment has not yet been created. Run `vagrant up` to
    create the environment. If a machine is not created, only the
    default provider will be shown. So if a provider is not listed,
    then the machine is not created for that environment.

    F:\vagvms\vagcode>vboxmanage list vms
    "first_vagcode" {3a1c41f3-3c01-4fa7-bb25-d68a66292b00}
    "vagtwo_default_1431119083293_66111" {03ee5819-dfc3-4bdd-bd10-a2e4e44350c5}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- start the vm from the GUI
- create a base box out of the vm using `vagrant box create BOX_ID`
- Use the box in your vagrant environment

However, the fact that you need to do this means that you did some changes in the vm manually. I would suggest to provision the VM using `Chef` or `Puppet`. Doing so, you can simply throw away the box and setup a new one.